# GIT for UNIX OS

Tags: git, unix

I need to install GIT on a UNIX IBM-AIX server OS.

But when I went to the git website I could not find the download for UNIX OS.

Where can i download the same.

Comment: Have you download the source tarfile and tried to build it?

Comment: Did you download file for GIT? what you tried?

Comment: No I havent tried it but wanted to confirm before I did coz i saw the downloads for Windows ,Linux and MAC OS only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know what sites you've checked, but everything you need should be at http://git-scm.com/

Answer (score 1):

@davis Colais, you can install git on UNIX. git have binary package for Windows, Mac, Linux. but as @Andy lester said, you can download source from [scm site of GIT](http://git-scm.com/) and detail description step of installation process given in its [Documentation site](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Installing-Git#Installing-from-Source)

may this step will help...